# Notation with covariant/contravariant derivative with product rule

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, klein-gordon-equation, variational-calculus

I have a question that should be rather simple, but i simply can not find enough information about it. I have searched and found a lot of related material, but not exactly like my problem.

I am trying to do a basic derivation of the Klein-Gordon equation from the lagrangian density: $\mathcal{L}(\phi)=-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi+m^2\phi^2)$ this I put into the EL-equation and that works fine except for one small part. The thing that confuses me is the notation, and I cant seem to find that much about it in my textbooks (Peskin & Schroeder and Srednicki). They do it in a line or two, and i am trying to do a lot more intermediate steps:

I get stuck on this bit of the derivation:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi)}[\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi]$

I know that it should give me $(2\partial^{\mu}\phi)$ but i can not see exactly why or how. I have found that $\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu} \equiv \partial^{2} \equiv \Box^{2} = \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}-\nabla^{2}$

and i feel like i am almost about to get it, but i still can not understand the notation. Would it be an idea to lower or raise on of the indices with a metric tensor?

For the sake of it, i have included all my equations underneath, but it is only the line mentioned above that i get stuck on.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}[-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi+m^2\phi^2)]-\partial_{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi)}[-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi+m^2\phi^2)]$

$0 - m^2\phi - \partial_{\mu} \frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi)}[-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi] - 0$

$\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi)}[\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi]-m^2\phi$

$\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}(2\partial^{\mu}\phi)-m^2\phi$

$\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\phi-m^2\phi$

$(\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}-m^2)\phi$

Comment: As a basic rule, you shouldn't repeat indices like that. What you wrote should really be $\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu  \phi)}[\partial_\nu \phi \partial^\nu \phi]$.

Comment: If i understand correctly, this would be due to the fact that when the metric tensor raises og lowers an index, the notation rule says it must be $g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}=\partial^{\nu}$. Is guess it makes it easier to keep track of the lowered/raised indices?

Comment: No, it's just bad notation. Einstein notation says that you should sum over an index when it appears twice, once upstairs and once downstairs. Your expression is ill formed, because the summation convention doesn't allow an index to appear three times. To make sense of what you wrote some implicit knowledge is needed that two of the $\mu$ should be summed over but the third one shouldn't.

Comment: Great, that i recognize from my books. I will remember that from now on, thanks for the info. Otherwise there is no difference in the $\mu$ and $\nu$, and if we had more terms we could add another greek letter right? But not latin because they are only spatial.

Comment: Using the GR notation $\partial_\mu \phi =: \phi_{,\mu}$ makes this a bit clearer, then you have $\phi^{,\mu} \phi_{,\mu}$ and in the derivative you have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^{,\mu}}$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at what exactly we mean with: $\partial_\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}(\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi)$ for that lets write the sums out:
\begin{align}
\partial_\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}(\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi)&=\left[\partial_0\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_0\phi)}+\sum_{i=1}^3\partial_i\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_i\phi)}\right]\left[(\partial_0\phi)(\partial^0\phi)+\sum_{j=1}^3(\partial_j\phi)(\partial^j\phi)\right]\\
&=\left[\partial_0\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_0\phi)}+\sum_{i=1}^3\partial_i\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_i\phi)}\right]\left[\pm(\partial_0\phi)(\partial_0\phi)\mp\sum_{i=j}^3(\partial_j\phi)(\partial_j\phi)\right]\\
&=\pm2\partial_0(\partial_0\phi)\mp2\sum_{i=1}^3\partial_i(\partial_i\phi)\\
&=2\partial_0(\partial^0\phi)+2\sum_{i=1}^3\partial_i(\partial^i\phi)\\
&=2\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi
\end{align}
The upper sign in the $\pm/\mp$ terms corresponds to the timelike-convention $(+---)$ and the lower sign to the spacelike-convention $(-+++)$ for the metric. 
The partial derivatives are only not-vanishing for $i=j$. The factor 2 comes from product rule or chain rule if you write $(\partial_\mu\phi)(\partial_\mu\phi)=(\partial_\mu\phi)^2$. The result in this compact form does not depend on the metric used: the  d'Alembert operator however does: 
\begin{align}
\partial_\mu\partial^\mu&=\partial_0\partial^0+\partial_i\partial^i\\
&=\pm\partial_0\partial_0\mp\partial_i\partial_i\\
&=\pm \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\mp\nabla^2.
\end{align}

OP seems to use the $(+---)$ convention judging from his d'Alembert operator. So 
$$\partial_\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}(\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi)=2(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2)\phi$$
 and for the Euler-Lagrange equation using OP's Lagrange density follows:

\begin{align}0&=\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}(-\frac 12\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-\frac 12 m^2 \phi^2)-\partial_\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}(-\frac 12\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-\frac 12 m^2 \phi^2)\\
&=-m^2\phi +(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2)\phi\\
0&=(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2-m^2)\phi.
\end{align}

Which is NOT the Klein-Gordon (KG) equation because it is impossible to derive the KG equation with the given Lagrange density. The correct Lagrange density is $$\mathcal{L}_{KG}=\frac 1 2 (\partial_\mu \phi)(\partial^\mu \phi)-m^2 \phi^2.$$ With $\mathcal{L}_{KG}$ one can derive the KG equation with proper signs:
$$0=(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2+m^2)\phi.$$ Sorry for not catching the fact that the Lagrange density is wrong sooner. A side note on that: OP mentioned *Peskin & Schroeder* they use the notation/convention $(\partial_\mu\phi)^2\equiv(\partial_\mu\phi)(\partial^\mu\phi)$ which could be the reason for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly the explanation i needed and it makes perfect sense. As an additional note, i want to make sure i understand your use of the metric tensor.
First i am starting out in the metric (-+++) with the given Lagrangian, then we use $g_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\mu}$ to get $\partial_{\nu}$, and the later we use $g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}$ to get $\partial^{\mu}$. If that is true, i also understand why javier wrote his comment about not repeating indices. Now can this be written short like $\partial_{\mu}=-\partial^{\mu}$ and its always true ?

Comment: And also it seems that its common not to include the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}$ in the equations - but all it does is flip the sign of the time/space-like terms right? That is why i want to know if my shorthand notation is correct, i think that is what my books use.

Comment: No that short notation $\partial_\mu=-\partial^\mu$ is not true for $\mu=0...3$. If you use the spacelike $(-+++)$ convention then $\partial_0=-\partial^0$ and $\partial_i=\partial^i$ for $i=1..3$. $g_{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}$ however is true for the Minkowski metric in both conventions. I do not "include" the tensor since sums like $g^{\mu\alpha}\partial_\alpha$ only have one non vanishing term $\partial^\alpha$ which can be written as $\pm\partial_\alpha$ by just multiplying it with the proper sign. This changes of basis are rather trivial in case of the Minkowski metric.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I cant seem to understand the signs when raising/lowering indeces then, if $\partial_0=-\partial^{0}$ when the opposite is happening in the line prior to the last equation. I thought that $\partial_{\mu}=(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\nabla)$ while $\partial^{\mu}=(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},-\nabla)$ which again is the opposite sign of the answer above. I am very confused about the signs due to choice of metric. I started out in (-+++) but your example was (+---) maybe that is why? - but i have tried multiple combinations now and cant seem to get the right signs.

Comment: I edited the answer trying to resolve those sign problems.